# Please describe how a vacuum flask/thermos works

Tags: thermodynamics

1. Please describe how a [vacuum flask/thermos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_flask) works.
2. How does the vacuum prevent convection/conduction/radiation?
3. How does the lid with the curvy lines prevent either of the aforementioned heat transfers?
4. If there are any other parts that may prevent heat transfer, please also list them.

Answer (score 1):

A thermos flask holds the liquid in a pocket in the middle of the flask, that pocket is surrounded by a smaller glass envelope that surrounds the inner pocket. This glass envelope is hollow- it is a vacuum, this means there is no air in it, so it is a fantastic insulator. It keeps hot things hot and cold things cold.

Comment: Yes, it stops the heat transfer through "conduction" predominantly, as the vacuum has no particles in it to vibrate and transfer the energy from inside the insulator to the outside.  Heat can still be lost through radiation however, because radiation can travel through a vacuum, as evidenced by the sun rays reaching earth.

Answer (score 0):

As James pointed out, the glass envelope is surrounded by vacuum, which precludes both conduction and convection. Also, the glass is usually coated in a thin metallic layer to make it reflective. High reflectivity also means low emissivity. High reflectivity means that infra red radiation is reflected from outside (keeping cold things cold) and low emissivity means that flask  doesn't radiate IR as efficiently (keeping warm things warm).