# How much conduction, radiation and convection influence in a thermos flask?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, education, thermal-conductivity, convection

It has been thoroughly repeated that thermos flasks prevent heat loss by minimizing heat conduction, radiation and convection from the bottle to its ambient. This has been [answered in this SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89411/). However, I have *never* seen a quantitative to qualitative approach to how much *each* of these transmission forms (conduction, radiation, and convection) actually contribute to heat loss in the flask.

This can be attributed to the difficulty of measuring the influence of each transmission form separetely. However, for instance, it could be the case where there is actually very little convection and the wall is actually only preventing conduction, and we've been teaching based on assumption and repetition for a long time.

Comment: Why don't you just do the calculation and work it out for yourself?

Comment: Are you being passive aggressive? Any calculation would be horrendous, this is all about experimental data.

Comment: No.  I'm being serious.  I don't see where it would be horrendous, and am confident that I can pretty easily do it.